# is it possible to build aws-cpp-sdk in 32 bit?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

Im integrating aws-cpp-sdk to my existing daemon(32 bit). is it possible to link aws-cpp-sdk in 32 bit architecture? What changes i have to make in cmake to build it in 32 bit?

Comment: Why it is not related to amazon-web-services tag? @john why did you remove it?

Comment: Oops! Added back. Didn't notice the 'aws' bit.

Comment: What platform / OS?  Why do you think 64 bit is required for building the SDK?

Comment: @ Dave, Because all libraries produced are of 64 bit by aws-cpp-sdk build. I have followed the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find anyway to do this. So, i upgraded my existing daemon to 64 bit architecture. Now im able to use aws-cpp-sdk which is 64 bit.